# Improve plots quality in log scale in Julia

Tags: plot, julia

I have a function solving two ODEs and joining the solution which gives a really nice plot in linear scales, but which has a high drop in quality in log scale depending on the parameters I use. In the code below, I plot the solution for two sets of parameters, in which you can see the first set is not smooth, while the second one is kind of okay. If I try to obtain a smoother visualisation using the saveat option in the second ODEs, `solclass = solve(probclass,Tsit5(),saveat=0.001)`, I get an error when plotting the second set: `ArgumentError: range step cannot be zero`. **Is there a way to obtain smooth linear-log other than manually changing the saveat option**? Also, I have tried using a few other backends, but they gave an error at ploting the solution.

````
using DifferentialEquations, Plots, RecursiveArrayTools

function alpha_of_phi!(s2,d,a0,ϕ₀)
    # α in the quantum phase 
    function quantum!(dv,v,p,ϕ)
        s2,d=p
        α = v[1]
        dv[1] = (ϕ*s2*sin(2*d*α)+2*d*sinh(s2*α*ϕ))/(-α*s2*sin(2*d*α)+2*d*cos(2*d*α)+2*d*cosh(s2*α*ϕ))
    end
    # When dα/dϕ = 1, we reach the classical regime, and stop the integration
    condition(v,ϕ,integrator) = (ϕ*s2*sin(2*d*v[1])+2*d*sinh(s2*v[1]*ϕ))/(-v[1]*s2*sin(2*d*v[1])+2*d*cos(2*d*v[1])+2*d*cosh(s2*v[1]*ϕ))==1.0
    affect!(integrator) = terminate!(integrator)
    cb = DiscreteCallback(condition,affect!)
    # Initial Condition at the bounce
    α₀ = [a0]
    classspan = (0,ϕ₀)
    probquant = ODEProblem(quantum!,α₀,classspan,(s2,d))
    solquant = solve(probquant,Tsit5(),callback=cb)

    # α in the classical phase
    function classic!(du,u,p,ϕ)
        αc = u[1]
        dαc = u[2]
        du[1] = dαc
        du[2] = 3*(-dαc^3/sqrt(2)+dαc^2+dαc/sqrt(2)-1)
    end
    # IC retrieved from end of quantum phase
    init = [last(solquant);1.0]
    classspan = (last(solquant.t),ϕ₀)
    probclass = ODEProblem(classic!,init,classspan)
    solclass = solve(probclass,Tsit5())

    # α(ϕ) for ϕ>0
    solu = append!(solquant[1,:],solclass[1,:]) # α
    solt = append!(solquant.t,solclass.t) # ϕ

    # α(ϕ) for ϕ<0
    soloppu = reverse(solu)
    soloppt = -reverse(solt)
    pop!(soloppu)
    pop!(soloppt)

    # Join the two solutions
    soltotu = append!(soloppu,solu)
    soltott = append!(soloppt,solt)
    soltot = DiffEqArray(soltotu,soltott)
end

plot(alpha_of_phi!(10000.0,-0.0009,0.0074847,2.0),yaxis=:log)
plot!(alpha_of_phi!(16.0,-0.1,0.00001,2.0))
```
````

Comment: I believe this question is more suitable for stackoverflow.

Comment: I can't answer your question. Do you not have access to the `DifferentialEquations` plot recipes with `DiffEqArray`? Have you seen this suggestion? https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-plot-y-axis-in-log-form-with-differential-equations/27073/8  You may find more focused help on discourse, rather than SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were plotting a solution returned by `solve` directly, then the Plots recipes for DifferentialEquations enable an optional keyword argument for `plot` entitled `plotdensity`, which would let you choose the number of points plotted, and thus smoothness, as described in the [docs](https://diffeq.sciml.ai/stable/basics/plot/#Density), e.g.:

```
plot(sol,plotdensity=10000)
```

However, this keyword appears to require a solution object, rather than a `DiffEqArray`. Consequently, your best bet will indeed be manually setting `saveat`. For this approach, `saveat = 0.01` would seem to be plenty to obtain fully smooth lines. However, this still gives the "range step cannot be zero" error you describe.

While I have no deep understanding of the system you are solving, an inspection of the results revealed duplicate timesteps in the results for `alpha_of_phi!(16.0,-0.1,0.00001,2.0)` run without `saveat`, suggesting that the classical simulation was being run with over a range of *no time*. In other words, this hints that `last(solquant.t)` may well be equal to or greater than `ϕ₀` with these parameters, resulting in a timespan of zero. If so, this will quite understandably fail when you request to `saveat` some finite time *within* that timespan `(last(solquant.t), ϕ₀)`.

Consequently, working on this hypothesis, if we just rewrite your function to check for this condition

```
using DifferentialEquations, Plots

function alpha_of_phi!(s2,d,a0,ϕ₀)
    # α in the quantum phase
    function quantum!(dv,v,p,ϕ)
       s2,d=p
       α = v[1]
       dv[1] = (ϕ*s2*sin(2*d*α)+2*d*sinh(s2*α*ϕ))/(-α*s2*sin(2*d*α)+2*d*cos(2*d*α)+2*d*cosh(s2*α*ϕ))
    end
    # When dα/dϕ = 1, we reach the classical regime, and stop the integration
    condition(v,ϕ,integrator) = (ϕ*s2*sin(2*d*v[1])+2*d*sinh(s2*v[1]*ϕ))/(-v[1]*s2*sin(2*d*v[1])+2*d*cos(2*d*v[1])+2*d*cosh(s2*v[1]*ϕ))==1.0
    affect!(integrator) = terminate!(integrator)
    cb = DiscreteCallback(condition,affect!)
    # Initial Condition at the bounce
    α₀ = [a0]
    classspan = (0,ϕ₀)
    probquant = ODEProblem(quantum!,α₀,classspan,(s2,d))
    solquant = solve(probquant,Tsit5(),callback=cb,saveat=0.01)

    # α in the classical phase
    function classic!(du,u,p,ϕ)
       αc = u[1]
       dαc = u[2]
       du[1] = dαc
       du[2] = 3*(-dαc^3/sqrt(2)+dαc^2+dαc/sqrt(2)-1)
    end
    if last(solquant.t) < ϕ₀
       # IC retrieved from end of quantum phase
       init = [last(solquant);1.0]
       classspan = (last(solquant.t),ϕ₀)
       probclass = ODEProblem(classic!,init,classspan)
       solclass = solve(probclass,Tsit5(),saveat=0.01)

       # α(ϕ) for ϕ>0
       solu = append!(solquant[1,:],solclass[1,:]) # α
       solt = append!(solquant.t,solclass.t) # ϕ
    else
       solu = solquant[1,:] # α
       solt = solquant.t # ϕ
    end

    # α(ϕ) for ϕ<0
    soloppu = reverse(solu)
    soloppt = -reverse(solt)
    pop!(soloppu)
    pop!(soloppt)

    # Join the two solutions
    soltotu = append!(soloppu,solu)
    soltott = append!(soloppt,solt)
    soltot = DiffEqArray(soltotu,soltott)
end

plot(alpha_of_phi!(10000.0,-0.0009,0.0074847,2.0),yaxis=:log)
plot!(alpha_of_phi!(16.0,-0.1,0.00001,2.0))
```

then we would seem to be in business!
[image: smooth log plot]